# How can I access internet with the proxy?

Tags: web-proxy

Our net provider use proxy (192.168.127.1  port 80) and we can't access internet, in older version of Tor I use bridges but in newer version I can't!
Please help me.
Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Dear Morteza, Are you using Tor Browser bundle? What type of OS are you using? What do you mean by "we can't access internet? Do you mean you can not access any site on internet or you can not access certain site on the internet? Do you mean it is a censorship problem or general network problem? Please elaborate on your situation.